# Just another "multiple definition first defined here" error

Tags: c++, include, multiple-definition-error

Okay, so I have been searching every forum on this "multiple definition first defined here" problem for the last 4 hours, and I guess I must be really stupid, but I can't seem to solve this problem.

I have the following files:

```
main.cpp
Socket.h
Socket.cpp
Server.h
Server.cpp
Packet.h
FileHandlerIn.h
FileHandlerOut.cpp
```

main.cpp includes only Server.h, which declare some functions, which are then defined in Server.cpp.
Server.cpp uses functions from Socket.cpp, FileHandlerOut.cpp and Packet.h, so the header files Socket.h, Packet.h and FileHandlerIn.h are included in Server.h. None of the other header files includes anything else than standard libraries.

What happens is that every function in Server.cpp and every function in Packet.h gets a multiple definition error. The reason I have functions inside Packet.h is that I have a struct defined, and the Packet.h functions all operate on the struct. I'm really confused about how I should correctly define these functions, so I can use them in other cpp files, and this might be part of my problem?

Comment: do you have include guards in your headers?

Comment: If you have functions, defined in header file, which are not member functions of struct/class, you'll need `inline`.

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimal example which is complete and still reproduces the problem, and then post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> every function in `Packet.h` gets a multiple definition error

If you're going to define functions in a header (outside a class definition), you'll need to mark them `inline`. This relaxes the One Definition Rule to allow definitions in multiple translation units.

You're still only allowed one definition in each translation unit, so make sure the headers have include guards.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the multiple definition problem with the Packet functions. The other multiple definition errors happening in Server.cpp was because the static members were defined in the header file and the error disappeared when I moved them to the cpp file.